# Transforming XML using an XSLT

Tags: vba, ms-access, xslt

I have a table in Access that has a field with my XSLT code in it. I want to import an XML document and transform it with the XSLT from the table. However, I get the following error:

`'-2147467259 (800004005)' the stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed xml document`

A check with an xml validator is successful.

```vb
Private Sub btnImport_Click()
Dim StrFileName As String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim daoRST As DAO.Recordset: Set daoRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Attachments"): Debug.Print daoRST.Fields("XML").Value:

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\*.xml"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            xslDoc.Load daoRST.Fields("XML").Value
            ' LOAD XML SOURCE
            xmlDoc.Load vrtSelectedItem
            ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
            xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc '<<ERROR HERE
            newDoc.Save "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml"

            ' APPEND TO TABLES
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml", acAppendData

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The error occurs at this line:

```vb
xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
```

Comment: Can you output the content of `xslDoc` just before you use it for the transformation and add it to your question? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629754/script16389-the-stylesheet-does-not-contain-a-document-element-the-stylesheet and similar google hits for your error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever loading a DOM object with MSXML from string as you are with recordset call, use the `loadXML` method rather than `load` which the latter expects a saved file on disk or url path.

So simply change:

```vb
xslDoc.Load daoRST.Fields("XML").Value
```

To:

```vb
xslDoc.LoadXML daoRST.Fields("XML").Value
```

---

By the way, you should not need to re-load XSLT with each iteration of loop but only once outside but the XML objects should be re-initialized inside loop not once outside. Consider following adjustment:

```vb
...
' LOAD XSL SCRIPT
xslDoc.LoadXML daoRST.Fields("XML").Value
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\*.xml"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            ' INITIALIZE XML OBJECTS
            Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

            ' LOAD XML SOURCE
            xmlDoc.Load vrtSelectedItem
            ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
            xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
            newDoc.Save "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml"

            ' APPEND TO TABLES
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml", acAppendData
        Next vrtSelectedItem                        
    End If
End With

' FREE RESOURCES
Set xmlDoc = Nothing
Set newDoc = Nothing
Set xslDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait! That solved it! I've been looking for that answer for 2 days! Also thank you for adjustment!