# Using VBA to Import XML into MS Access with xslt within VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

I am trying to import an XML file into MS-Access. At this point, it is a saved importmethod where the XML file is transformed by a XSLT file. By clicking in a form, a Macro calls the importmethod.

I want to make this into VBA and the goal is to have also the XSLT file written in the VBA. This is to have no dependencies on separate files and no risk of someone removing the XSLT file and Access no longer importing the file.

I have found code from similar stackoverflow questions that show how to do part of my question, but those refer to a separate XSLT file.

Can someone help me put the XSLT into the VBA-coda

Pasting the XSLT code into the xslDoc.Load results in errors.

```
Public Sub TransformAndImportXML()
    ' INCLUDE Microsoft XML, v3.0 REFERENCE
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XML\Input.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XML\File.xsl"

    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\XML\Output.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\XML\Output.xml"
    MsgBox "Successfully transformed and imported XML!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transforming XML using an XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309079/transforming-xml-using-an-xslt)

Comment: @June7, I am aware of that question and used the code as described in another question. Difference for me is that I want to describe the xsl code within VBA, not as a separate file

Comment: So what part of that link's code did you use? Did you save XSLT code in a table and use LoadXML method?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck thing in the wrong direction. I have changed my code to first printing the xsl-file in a specific folder using

```
Public Function CreateXSLFile()
Dim XSLDirectory As String
Dim XSLFile As String

XSLDirectory = "XXXXX"
XSLFile = XSLDirectory & "\YYYY.xsl"
Open XSLFile For Output As #1

Print #1, "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" version=""1.0"">"
Print #1, "<xsl:output method=""xml"" version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" indent=""yes"" />"
Print #1, ""
...
Close #1 

End Function
```

Than the macro still calls the saved importmethod.

Than the macro calls a function to delete the XSL-file if found:

```
Public Function RemoveXSLFile()
Dim XSLDirectory As String
Dim XSLFile As String

XSLDirectory = "XXXXX"
XSLFile = XSLDirectory & "\YYYY.xsl"

If Len(Dir(XSLFile)) > 0 Then
   SetAttr XSLFile, vbNormal
   Kill XSLFile
End If
End Function
```

This way i'm sure no-one will remove the xsl-file accidently and I don't need to include the Microsoft v XML3.0.

Kind regards